# How to make an additional API call once inside a detail view?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm fetching books from an endpoint as such:

```
    class APIManager: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var books = [Book]()

    
    func fetchBooks() {
        if let url = URL(string: urlEndpoint) {
            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
            let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
                if error == nil {
                    if let safeData = data {
                        do {
                            let response = try JSONDecoder().decode([Book].self, from: safeData)
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                self.books = response
                            }
                        } catch {
                            print(error)
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }
    }
    
}
```

My BookView looks like this:

```
struct BookView: View {
    @ObservedObject var apiManager = APIManager()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(apiManager.books) { book in
                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: BookDetailView(id: book.id, chapter: book.chapters),
                        label: {
                            HStack {
                                Text(book.name)
                                Spacer()
                                Text(book.testament)
                            }
                        })
                    
                }.navigationBarTitle("Book Title Here")
            }.onAppear {
                self.apiManager.fetchBooks()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When navigating to `BookDetailView` - I need to make another API call to fetch additional details about the book (such as chapters), given the book id that is passed here:

```
...
destination: BookDetailView(id: book.id, chapter: book.chapters)
...
```

Do I simply repeat the process and make another function in my `APIManager` class and add another `@Published var chapters = [Chapter]()`

And inside `BookDetailView` go

```
// Loop through each chapter here
// I want to display chapter details in this view
Text("You are viewing book id \(id). Chapter: \(chapter)").onAppear {

            self.apiManager.fetchChapterDetails()         
}
```

Doing so returns `UIScrollView does not support multiple observers implementing`

Whats the procedure here?

Comment: Yes or you can use a view model code in between and let it call the ApiManager and hold the result

Comment: I would suggest biting the bullet, and learning Combine, then you can then use .sink { book in ... } and assign it to the Publisher, and it will work much better in SwiftUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest making a separate ViewModel for the Detail Page. In that ViewModel you can pass in the id of the Book and make a separate API function. Also think about extracting the API Calls into a Service class, which being called from the ViewModel.

The Detail View and ViewModel could look like that...

```
class BookDetailViewModel: ObservableObject {
    let bookId: Int
    
    init(withBookId bookId: Int) {
        self.bookId = bookId
    }
    
    func fetchBookInfos() {
        // ...
    }
}

struct BookDetailView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: BookDetailViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Text("Book id \(viewModel.bookId)")
            }.onAppear {
                self.viewModel.fetchBookInfos()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When creating the Detail View, pass in the ViewModel.

Comment: Hmm, what is different here from the way I'm doing it?

Comment: @erikvm As I understood is, the difference is, that davidev suggests to refactor your design and define a "Model" (aka abstract "Service") as a layer to a network service which is used in a "View Model" which takes over the role of your APIManager (this is applied Dependency Inversion Principle). Then, he suggests to use an additional Detail View Model, which - as you can see - needs to be created in the parent view of the Detail View.

Comment: So in my `BookView`, I'd use something like:

`destination: BookDetailView(viewModel: BookDetailViewModel.init(withBookId: book.id)),`? 

Where and how do I store all the information about the response from my second api call?

Comment: @erikvm Yes, basically. Your followup question is about how do "Master" and "Detail" components communicate to each other. Well, depending on _where_ (ViewModel, Views or concrete Services) you want to do this, there are different approaches. If you want pass data or actions from the Detail View to the parent, you may use callback closures, which you set up from the parent in the detail view, and which get called from the detail, example action: `let done: (Value) -> Void` or `let cancel: () -> Void`. These are functions set by the parent view, and called by the detail in certain actions.

Comment: Ah, I don't want to pass information from detail view to parent. I'm just confused about the approach. Not sure what logic goes in what file and how the response from my second API call is stored on the detail view